# modify child component using its reference

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to modify child component through the parent using its reference, but it doesn't seem to work, here's what I've tried already:

```js
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // I'm getting an error here that rightSide doesn't exist on App, and I got `Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject '` when setting rightSide= useRef(null) 
        this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }

    render() { 
        <RightSide
            containerRef={ref => (this.rightSide = ref)}
        />
    }
}

const RightSide = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <div
            className="right-side"
            ref={props.containerRef}
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            <div className="inner-container">
                <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
``
```

Comment: I'm guessing you missed some code in your example, but change `this.rightSide.classList` to `this.rightSide.current.classList`. This seems very much like an anti-pattern though. You shouldn't be mutating the DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can see your error from render function you are not returning anything that is why you see .classList.add() as is not a function.

This is how you render should be

```
render() { 
    return <RightSide
        containerRef={ref => (this.rightSide = ref)}
    />
}
```